# Encoded raw docx base64 string preview on react

Tags: javascript, base64, preview

How do I preview a raw base64 string without decoding and get a preview on my website? (there are tools for images, pdf but I don't have anything for office).

Comment: please update your question with some code examples and your try's history.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in an iframe and for `src`, pass in document url either from Google docs or Office 360

```
<iframe src=INSERT_DOCUMENT_URL frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Comment: but it's encoded I need a way to do it without decoding it.